# Pandas - Match List Values to Index within a Dataset Name and List Value to New Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe like so:

```
Dataset                             Volume_ft3
Sonar_Raster_0.tif                  2055
Sonar_Raster_1.tif                  6784
Sonar_Raster_FocalMean_5x5_0.tif    2045
Sonar_Raster_FocalMean_5x5_1.tif    6752
```

I want to append a new column called "Sonar_Points" that matches values from a list to the dataset based on the unique numerical identifier in the Dataset name.

My list is [5525,4374] and I need to look for the index number in the Dataset name, match it to  the list index, then output that value in a new column to where this is the resulting dataframe:

```
Dataset                             Volume_ft3    Sonar_Points
Sonar_Raster_0.tif                  2055          5525
Sonar_Raster_1.tif                  6784          4374
Sonar_Raster_FocalMean_5x5_0.tif    2045          5525
Sonar_Raster_FocalMean_5x5_1.tif    6752          4374
```

I've tried the below code, but it doesn't account for datasets with the same index.

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(Sonar_pts_List, columns=['Sonar_Points']),ignore_index=False)
```

Comment: hi @Austin, could you please provide more information? We would need the actual script and example dataset to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the dataset identifier into a separate column and then use that to `merge` the data with the list of Sonar Points values:

```py
df['spi'] = df['Dataset'].str.extract(r'_(\d+)\.').astype(int)
df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Sonar_Points']), left_on='spi', right_index=True).drop('spi', axis=1).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                            Dataset  Volume_ft3  Sonar_Points
0                Sonar_Raster_0.tif        2055          5525
1                Sonar_Raster_1.tif        6784          4374
2  Sonar_Raster_FocalMean_5x5_0.tif        2045          5525
3  Sonar_Raster_FocalMean_5x5_1.tif        6752          4374
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.extract`.

Note: this will **fail** if there is an index that exceeds the length of list.

```
l = [5525, 4374]

df["Sonar_Points"] =  [l[i] for i in 
                       df["Dataset"].str.extract("_(\d+)\.", expand=False).astype(int)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                            Dataset  Volume_ft3  Sonar_Points
0                Sonar_Raster_0.tif        2055          5525
1                Sonar_Raster_1.tif        6784          4374
2  Sonar_Raster_FocalMean_5x5_0.tif        2045          5525
3  Sonar_Raster_FocalMean_5x5_1.tif        6752          4374
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this issue with pd.concat since the length of each dataframe match.

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(Sonar_pts_List, columns='Sonar_Points')], axis=1)
```

you can also assign new columns to a *dataframe* with matching indexes using the following:

```
df['Sonar_Points'] = Sonar_pts_List
```

if an error occurs from the above. Simply clone a small column (that is a column with cheap values as to not take up too much resources) to be able to *backfill* the new values.

An example:

```
df['Sonar_Points'] = df['Volume_ft3']
df['Sonar_Points'] = Sonar_pts_List
```